# JSON output from PHP using d3.json

Tags: php, javascript, json, d3.js

I created a PHP file to query JSON output. JSON output from the PHP file for a particular filter "testPHP.php?number=123" is

```
[{"source":"AB","target":"AC","type":"true"},{"source":"UB","target":"EP","type":"true"},{"source":"US","target":"UR","type":"lie"},{"source":"BS","target":"QW","type":"lie"},{"source":"UW","target":"EA","type":"lie"}]
```

I have tried this in html file to read the JSON output to links variable

```
var links; // a global
d3.json("testPHP.php?number=123", function(error, json) {
  if (error) return console.warn(error);
  links = json;
});
```

But, it seems like data is not stored in links.
How do I store the data in `var links`?

Basically, I want to replace `var links` in this https://gist.github.com/mbostock/1153292 to that from JSON output from PHP.

EDIT:
Or `http://localhost:8080` is causing the problem?

Comment: Your JSON is invalid.  How are you producing this JSON?  Your last object in the array is missing a quote.

Comment: Typo error. Changed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The d3.json call is asynchronous; the code included after your callback is executed before the "links" variable has been populated.

```
var links; // a global
d3.json("testPHP.php?number=123", function(error, json) {
  if (error) return console.warn(error);
  links = json;

  console.log(links); // your links are populated here

  // include the rest of your app here
});

// links is still undefined here because the success callback hasn't been run yet
```

Answer (score -1):

you would need to write `links = [{"source":"AB","target":"AC","type":"true"},{"source":"UB","target":"EP","type":"true"},{"source":"US","target":"UR","type":"lie"},{"source":"BS","target":"QW","type":"lie"},{"source":"UW,"target":"EA","type":"lie"}]`

At that point links will hold that information. You may however want to consider an array.

Comment: i need to use the json output from php file!