# Reading d3js interactive graph data from mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, d3.js

Im trying to create an interactive network in d3js for which ive used php to fetch the data in json format inside the d3js.

This is what Ive written :-
**MY_CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>TEST</title>
<style>

.node circle {
  cursor: pointer;
  stroke: #3182bd;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  pointer-events: none;
  text-anchor: middle;
}

line.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #9ecae1;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>


<script>
d3.json("data.php.php", function(error, links) {
var nodes = {};
root=json;
console.log(root)
// Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
links.forEach(function(link) {
    link.source = nodes[link.source] || 
        (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
    link.target = nodes[link.target] || 
        (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});
    link.value = +link.value;
});

var width = 1700,
    height = 1000;

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .linkDistance(150)
    .charge(-120)
    .gravity(.05)
    .size([width, height])
    .on("tick", tick);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
    node = svg.selectAll(".node");

flatten(link); //to set ids
setParents(link, null);
collapseAll(link);
link.children = link._children;
link._children = null;
update();

function update() {
  var nodes = flatten(link),
      links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);
  // Restart the force layout.
  force
      .nodes(nodes)
      .links(links)
      .start();

  // Update links.
  link = link.data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  link.exit().remove();

  link.enter().insert("line", ".node")
      .attr("class", "link");

  // Update nodes.
  node = node.data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id; });

  node.exit().remove();

  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .on("click", click)
      .call(force.drag);

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
      .attr("r", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.size) / 10 || 4.5; });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  node.select("circle")
      .style("fill", color);
}

function tick() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
}

function color(d) {
  return d._children ? "#3182bd" // collapsed package
      : d.children ? "#c6dbef" // expanded package
      : "#fd8d3c"; // leaf node
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return; // ignore drag
  if (d.children) {
      collapseAll(d);
  } else {
      if (d._parent){
          d._parent.children.forEach(function(e){
              if (e != d){
                  collapseAll(e);
              }
          });
      }
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update();
}

function collapseAll(d){
    if (d.children){
        d.children.forEach(collapseAll);
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
    }
    else if (d._childred){
        d._children.forEach(collapseAll);
    }
}

// Returns a list of all nodes under the link.
function flatten(link) {
  var nodes = [], i = 0;

  function recurse(node) {
    if (node.children) node.children.forEach(recurse);
    if (!node.id) node.id = ++i;
    nodes.push(node);
  }
  recurse(link);
  return nodes;
}

function setParents(d, p){
    d._parent = p;
  if (d.children) {
      d.children.forEach(function(e){ setParents(e,d);});
  } else if (d._children) {
      d._children.forEach(function(e){ setParents(e,d);});
  }
}   

</script>
</body>
```

The problem is that its not displaying anything. I want the above page to display the data which its fetching from the mysql (in form of json using php) like this :-
**SAMPLE_CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Stores_Network_Demo</title>
<style>

.node circle {
  cursor: pointer;
  stroke: #3182bd;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  pointer-events: none;
  text-anchor: middle;
}

line.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #9ecae1;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    root = {
 "name": "Chocolate", "tag":"class",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "Wafer", "tag":"subclass",
   "children": [
    {
      "name": "Nestle", "tag":"company",
     "children": [
      {"name": "KitKat", "tag":"product"}
     ]
    }
   ]
  },

  {
   "name": "White", "tag":"subclass",
   "children": [
    {
      "name": "Nestle", "tag":"company",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Milkybar", "tag":"product"}
     ]
    }
   ]
  },

    {
   "name": "Caramel", "tag":"subclass",
   "children": [
    {
      "name": "Nestle", "tag":"company",
     "children": [
      {"name": "BarOne", "tag":"product"}
     ]
    }
   ]
  },    
    {
   "name": "Milk", "tag":"subclass",
   "children": [
    {
      "name": "Nestle", "tag":"company",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Nestle Milk", "tag":"product"}
     ]
    },  {
      "name": "Cadbury", "tag":"company",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Dairy Milk", "tag":"product"}
     ]
    }
   ]
  }




 ]
};

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .linkDistance(150)
    .charge(-120)
    .gravity(.05)
    .size([width, height])
    .on("tick", tick);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
    node = svg.selectAll(".node");

flatten(root); //to set ids
setParents(root, null);
collapseAll(root);
root.children = root._children;
root._children = null;
update();

function update() {
  var nodes = flatten(root),
      links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);
  // Restart the force layout.
  force
      .nodes(nodes)
      .links(links)
      .start();

  // Update links.
  link = link.data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  link.exit().remove();

  link.enter().insert("line", ".node")
      .attr("class", "link");

  // Update nodes.
  node = node.data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id; });

  node.exit().remove();

  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .on("click", click)
      .call(force.drag);

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
      .attr("r", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.size) / 10 || 4.5; });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  node.select("circle")
      .style("fill", color);
}

function tick() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
}

function color(d) {
  return d._children ? "#3182bd" // collapsed package
      : d.children ? "#c6dbef" // expanded package
      : "#fd8d3c"; // leaf node
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return; // ignore drag
  if (d.children) {
      collapseAll(d);
  } else {
      if (d._parent){
          d._parent.children.forEach(function(e){
              if (e != d){
                  collapseAll(e);
              }
          });
      }
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update();
}

function collapseAll(d){
    if (d.children){
        d.children.forEach(collapseAll);
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
    }
    else if (d._childred){
        d._children.forEach(collapseAll);
    }
}

// Returns a list of all nodes under the root.
function flatten(root) {
  var nodes = [], i = 0;

  function recurse(node) {
    if (node.children) node.children.forEach(recurse);
    if (!node.id) node.id = ++i;
    nodes.push(node);
  }
  recurse(root);
  return nodes;
}

function setParents(d, p){
    d._parent = p;
  if (d.children) {
      d.children.forEach(function(e){ setParents(e,d);});
  } else if (d._children) {
      d._children.forEach(function(e){ setParents(e,d);});
  }
}


</script>
```

MY_CODE is fetching data from mysql-databse in json, via data.php . I.E where/in_which variable is the data being stored by this call :- `d3.json("data.php.php", function(error, links)`

Whereas SAMPLE_CODE has hardcoded root{} data.

ANd this is what exactly my question is related to, i.e. how do I do the same operations as done on root{} (in the SAMPLE_CODE) on my json_data fetched via data.php in MY_CODE ?
In order to make MY_CODE work like SAMPLE_CODE , I need to replace the root{} data in SAMPLE_CODE with the data that is being fetched from the data.php page in a proper format in MY_CODE for it to work. But I dont know where and what line to change so as to make the page of MY_CODE appear like SAMPLE_CODE.

SAMPLE json_array being read data.php :

```
[{"source":"2","target":"211","value":"1"},{"source":"21","target":"24","value":"1"},{"source":"2","target":"214","value":"1"},{"source":"3","target":"202","value":"1"},{"source":"2","target":"214","value":"1"},{"source":"2","target":"214","value":"1"},.........]
```

Comment: @shalini thanks for the edit. That is basically what im asking. Where exactly is the data.php storing the values? in which variable ?

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16512218/json-output-from-php-using-d3-json) may help you

Comment: Ive added this : root=json; console.log(root) , So the json_array should be getting fed in root (and generating an array as in case of SAMPLE_CODE) But still it doesnt work !!!  Please help

Comment: @Gilsha thanks, Ive incorporated those changes in my code and updated the same on this page in MY_CODE, but still not working

Comment: In this code `d3.json("data.php.php", function(error, links)` , `links` contains the json response. Try  `root=links;` instead of `root=json`. Here `json` is undefined.

Comment: @Gilsha Ji pls help me on this

Comment: Do you want to generate tree node structure from the links array? Can you use underscore.js? Underscore is one of the best tools to process arrays and json data.

Comment: @Gilsha this is the kind of expand-collapse network I want http://bl.ocks.org/dukevis/6583393 . I know the way Im reading the json array by d3.json isnt getting stored properly so as to be of any use. But how to fix it is an issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64383/discussion-between-gilsha-and-rzach).