# How to update a graph in D3.js when pressing a button?

Tags: php, database, d3.js

I am working on a graph that shows the temperature, date and time. Until now everything is working pretty good, but in order to get the new values from my MySQL database in need to completely refresh my page.
I want to be able to update the graph without pressing the Refresh button.
This is the code:

```
<?php require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/assets/php/getTemp.php' ); ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<head>
    <title>RPi</title>
</head>

<style>

div.tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 120px;
    height: 28px;
    padding: 3px;
    font: 12px sans-serif;
    background: lightgrey;
    border: 0px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    pointer-events: none;
}


body { font: 14px Arial;}

path {
    stroke: #FF8C00;
    stroke-width: 3;
    fill: none;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 2;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.grid .tick {
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-opacity: 0.3;
    shape-rendering: geometricPrecision;
}
.grid path {
          stroke-width: 0;
}


</style>
<body>


<div id="option">
    <input name="updateButton"
           type="button"
           value="Update"
           onclick="updateData()"
    />
</div>


<!-- load the d3.js library -->
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<script>


var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width =  800 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").parse;
var formatTime = d3.time.format("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S");

var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);


var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(5);

var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.datetime); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.temperature); });

var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("opacity", 0);

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform",
              "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

function make_x_axis() {
    return d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom")
        .ticks(5)
}

function make_y_axis() {
     return d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left")
        .ticks(5)
}

<?php echo "data=".$json_data.";" ?>
data.forEach(function(d) {
 d.datetime = parseDate(d.datetime);
 d.temperature = +d.temperature;
});

x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.datetime; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.temperature; })]);


svg.append("path")
 .attr("class", "line")
 .attr("d", valueline(data));


svg.selectAll("dot")
    .data(data)
.enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 4)
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.datetime); })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.temperature); })
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
        div.transition()
             .duration(200)
             .style("opacity", 1);
        div.html(formatTime(d.datetime) + "<br/>" + d.temperature + " &#8451")
             .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 16) + "px")
             .style("top", (d3.event.pageY + 16) + "px")
         .style("position", "absolute");
        })
     .on("mouseout", function(d) {
         div.transition()
            .duration(50)
            .style("opacity", 0);
});

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "grid")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(make_x_axis()
      .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
      .tickFormat("")
)

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "grid")
  .call(make_y_axis()
      .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
      .tickFormat("")
)

svg.append("g")
 .attr("class", "x axis")
 .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
 .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
 .attr("class", "y axis")
 .call(yAxis);


</script>
</body>
```

I tried to do this:

```
function updateData() {

//d3.json("/assets/php/getTemp.php", function(error, data) {
        <?php echo "data=".$json_data.";" ?>
        data.forEach(function(d) {
        d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")
        d.datetime = parseDate(d.datetime);
        d.temperature = +d.temperature;
});

x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.datetime; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.temperature; })]);

var svg = d3.select("body").transition();

    svg.select(".line") 
        .duration(750)
        .attr("d", valueline(data));
    svg.select(".x.axis")
        .duration(750)
        .call(xAxis);
    svg.select(".y.axis") 
        .duration(750)
        .call(yAxis);
};
```

but nothing happens, not even an error.

If it matters this is the PHP code used to get the temperatures and time form MySQL:

```
<?php
$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = 'admin';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=temp_database",
                               $username, $password);


    $sth = $dbh->prepare("
       SELECT  `datetime`, `temperature` FROM  `tempLog`
    ");
    $sth->execute();


    $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


    $dbh = null;

}
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

$json_data = json_encode($result);
?>
```

What i need to do ?

Comment: Looks right to me. Could you possibly stick this in a jsfiddle with an example of the kind of data you're using?

Comment: Of course: https://jsfiddle.net/zzmoL7Le/4/ I hope the link is OK.

Comment: Problem seems to be the formatting you're performing on the data in the `updateData` function. If you comment that section out the code runs

Answer (score 0):

Look into using the d3.json function. This lets you get json from php scripts without reloading the entire page from scratch. It's AJAX stuff, but the d3 helper functions hide the details.

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests

PS. Remember, it will be an asynchronous call, so see the accepted answer here as well:
[JSON output from PHP using d3.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16512218/json-output-from-php-using-d3-json)

---

As to why it doesn't work currently, my hunch*, though there's not enough info to confirm, is that there's no change because it's always the same data, so nothing will change

```
<?php echo "data=".$json_data.";" ?>
```

That line^^^ in `updateData` is evaluated once at the start and then the whole function is plonked into the javascript realm. However many times you then call `updateData`, that previously generated javascript variable (`data={some_json}`) won't change without reloading the php page that generated `updateData`, even if you call that database related php that generates the server side variable.

*could be nonsense, but the bit above the line is still right